# Why does Magento 2 use RequireJS `map` instead of `path`

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

In Magento 2's RequireJS implementation, many core modules use a configuration something like this

```
map: {
    '*': {
        editTrigger:   'mage/edit-trigger',
        addClass:      'Magento_Translation/add-class'
    }
}
```

In RequireJS, the `map` configuration directive allows developers to tell RequireJS

> When you load module X, and it uses module Y, replace module Y with module Z -- **but only for Module X**

Or, in code

```
map: {
    'modulex':{
        'moduley':'modulez'
    }
}
```

The `map` feature basically allows you to swap out module definitions via configuration -- in Magento speak, it's a module rewrite feature for javascript.

What's not clear to me though is Magento's heavy use of the `*` as the key for the `map` property.

```
map: {
    '*': {
        editTrigger:   'mage/edit-trigger',
        addClass:      'Magento_Translation/add-class'
    }
}
```

The `*` basically says *do this mapping for **all** modules, and its intended use case is is [provide a base module aliasing](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) that can be changed for more specific modules.

However, Magento appears to use it as a replacement for [RequireJS's `paths` property](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths).  i.e. it seems Magento could have achieved the same thing with the following

```
paths: {
    'editTrigger': 'mage/edit-trigger',
    'addClass':    'Magento_Translation/add-class',
}
```

and then selectively does specific mapping when needed.

Does anyone know why Magento chose `map:*` as its method for path aliasing?  i.e -- is my understanding of the difference between `map` and `path` incomplete -- or is this one of those "Six of one, half dozen the other" things.  Or is there some additional behavior Magento gets by doing it this way.

Not asking to solve a specific problem, asking to clarify any misunderstandings of RequireJS and Magento's implementation before I start writing heavily about it :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After researching this a bit more, I have found one major difference between `map` and `path`.  I'm not sure if the Magento core team makes deliberate use of this, but per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199309/4668) when you're define a `map` configuration, you're actually defining a **prefix** for mappings.  i.e. Not only will this

```
map: {
    '*': {
        editTrigger:   'mage/edit-trigger',
    }
}
```

ensure the loading the `editTrigger` module actually loads the `mage/edit-trigger` module, **but also** that `editTrigger/foo` would load the `mage/edit-trigger/foo` module.

The `paths` directive is not a prefix mapping.  It's a simple one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Also, if I recollect correctly, `path: {foo: 'bar'}` will block you from requiring `bar` explicitly and will only allow to access it by `foo` alias.